# Batch Echo Stuttering

Tags: batch-file, echo

So, I  had just been playing around with batch trying to make a batch file that puts 1s & 0s all across the screen (my monitor is small), but I ran into some "stuttering" if you'd call it that. It bumps up a line for a split second, and then goes back down, and it does it constantly.

```
@echo off
color 0a
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:repeat
for /l %%g in (1,1,32) do (
set /a num=!random! %%2
<NUL set /p=!num!   
)
echo.
echo. <--- Where it stutters
goto repeat
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you mean that the output makes a small pause, then I suggest you to change the `echo.` by `echo/`... For further details, see [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&start=0)

Comment: It doesn't really pause up, it just bumps everything up one line for a split second and then goes back to normal, and putting the slash instead of the period didn't do much of anything :/

Comment: Then, change `:repeat` line by `for /L %%a in () do (` and change `goto repeat` by `)`; this will make the code run faster.

Comment: It doesn't do it as much, but even still it can't keep up all the time

Answer (score 0):

you may as well make a new batch file that goes like this:

@echo off
color 0a
:onesandzeroes
echo 100101010010100101010101010000010101001010100101010101010011101010010101010
echo 010110000100101001110001001101001110000011000110101010000101111001100101100
echo 000010111100011001011100010100010100110111011000100101110100000010101000101
echo 110010101110011011100001111100010100001010011000000010111110010000010001001
goto :onesandzeroes